# how to make documentation with phpdoc

Tags: php, documentation-generation, phpdoc

I had run the this command in my code folder .

```
$ phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -f user.php -t docs
```

It created the folder docs and with html documetation of user.
Now if i want to add more file to this package , how should i add to it .

I tried

```
$ phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -f gib.php -t docs
```

but it doesn't add it replace, the user.php

and in this documentation i didn't get the searching facility , is i can get the searching facility in phpdoc , or is any other documentation software can provide me searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this command for converting directory , and ignore the upload and url directory,
-t is the target folder
http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html

```
phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -d ryapi -i uploads/,url/ -t docs
```

for searching i am using to convert to pdf.